# PGP Encryption and Decryption using

Tags: java, pgp

Please any one can post a good tutorial or any good example which will working on PGP key using java.

1) How PGP works?
2) Whats is primary key and private keys concepts ?
3) how to implement PGP using public and private keys?

A good example code which is using PGP encryption and Decryption .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://www.google.com/#hl=be&source=hp&q=PGP+tutorial&btnG=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA+Google&gbv=2&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=9e9e8a1fa9d229ba&biw=1280&bih=892

Answer (score 2):

Q1 and Q2 should be easily answerable with a quick Google search.

For Q3 - I would recommend you don't attempt to implement PGP from scratch without a very good reason (and certainly not if you are still flummoxed by Q1 and Q2). If you wish to play with PGP from Java, try using the BouncyCastle libraries, which offer PGP support.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Duncan. Can you provide me a good example java code which offers pgp key authentication , It will be moe helpfull for me to understand this Concept.